# How to create dynamic VBA Ribbon XML button?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make my button "Lock Cells" and "Unlock Cells" become disabled once it checks the Activesheet is protected and if the ActiveSheet is not protected it will go back to enabled.Is there any way to do so?
Below is my XML ribbon

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" OnLoad="Module1.OnLoad">
<ribbon>
    <tabs>
        <tab id="customTab" label="Tool" insertAfterMso="TabHome">
            <group id="customGroup" label="Group1">
                <button id="lockButton" label="Lock Cells" size="large" onAction="LockCells" image="img_lockcell5" />
                <button id="unlockButton" label="Unlock Cells" size="large" onAction="conUnderlineSub" image="img_unlockcell3" />
                <separator id="separator"/>
                <button idMso="SheetProtect" label="Protect Sheet" size="large" onAction="conUnderlineSub" imageMso="SheetProtect" />
            </group>
        </tab>
    </tabs>
</ribbon>
```

Code in module:

```
Public bolEnabled As Boolean
Public myRibbon As IRibbonUI

Sub OnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
Set myRibbon = ribbon
OnLoad_Exit:
Exit Sub
End Sub

Sub CheckProtect(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
returnedVal = bolEnabled
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

If Sh.ProtectContents = True Then
bolEnabled = False
Else
bolEnabled = True
End If
End Sub
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable or to disable the buttons "Lock Cells" and "Unlock Cells" when you activate worksheet, you have to add `getEnabled` attribute to the Ribbon XML, make the appropriate Subs and place into Workbook module (Sub Workbook_SheetActivate) `myRibbon.InvalidateControl` statements:

Ribbon XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui"  onLoad="OnLoad">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab id="customTab" label="Tool" insertAfterMso="TabHome">
                <group id="customGroup" label="Group1">
                    <button id="lockButton" label="Lock Cells" size="large" onAction="LockCells" image="img_lockcell5" getEnabled="LB_Enabled" />
                    <button id="unlockButton" label="Unlock Cells" size="large" onAction="conUnderlineSub" image="img_unlockcell3" getEnabled="UB_Enabled" />
                    <separator id="separator"/>
                    <button idMso="SheetProtect" label="Protect Sheet" size="large" onAction="conUnderlineSub" imageMso="SheetProtect" />
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

---

```
'Module1
Option Explicit

Public myRibbon As IRibbonUI

Private Sub OnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set myRibbon = ribbon
End Sub

'lockButton (element: button, attribute: getEnabled), 2007
Private Sub LB_Enabled(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef enabled)
    enabled = Not ActiveSheet.ProtectContents
End Sub

'unlockButton (element: button, attribute: getEnabled), 2007
Private Sub UB_Enabled(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef enabled)
    enabled = Not ActiveSheet.ProtectContents
End Sub
```

---

```
'Workbook module
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    ' refresh the controls on the Ribbon - callback getEnabled Sub
    myRibbon.InvalidateControl "lockButton"
    myRibbon.InvalidateControl "unlockButton"
End Sub
```

It is not clear from your code what exactly the "Lock Cells" and "Unlock Cells" buttons should do. Also note that the "Lock Cells" button and the "SheetProtect" button run the same `onAction = "conUnderlineSub"` procedure, which may cause the program to behave incorrectly.